# No app name specified in owncloud

Tags: owncloud

I am trying to create an app which displays "Hello World". This app is explained in Owncloud developer manual. I have followed all the procedure explained in manual. But the app is not enabling. What is the problem? It shows the message "No app name specified". Please help me how to enable this app.

Answer (score 10):

According to http://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/developer_manual/app/info.html the **id** field in appinfo/info.xml should be the same as the name of the app folder. If you have app in the folder 'test_app', then in 'test_app/appinfo/info.xml' you must have

```
<info>
  <id>test_app</id>
...
</info>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your probleme is the name of app in the file and the name of folder

Comment: This does not exactly tell anyone what to do about the problem.

Comment: Please rename the app folder name to match the app name. It works for me. For example, for the app "OCLife", the folder name should be "oclife".

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install libxml-xpath-perl
cd owncloud/apps/myPlugin; 

realName=$(xpath -e '//id' appinfo/info.xml |sed -e 's,.*<id>\([^<]*\)</id>.*,\1,g');

cd ..;

mv myPlugin $realName
```

This script will automate extraction of the plugin folder name  should be.

Then , it renames that folder by the name found at `appinfo/info.xml`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name of folder is not equal to id attribute on xml.
To resolve this, you only rename plugin folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the "info.xml"(which locates in /apps/{plugin_folder}/appinfo/) as you can find what name the plugin is called, as the others have stated, then rename the {plugin_folder} to the name that you found, and then... just go to enable it. 
All done!